# Avoid overlapping events with EventQuery by Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, events, gdata-api, google-calendar-api, overlapping

Maybe the answer is simple, but I have not found any hint pointing in the right direction:

```
            EventQuery calQuery = new EventQuery(_calendarFeedString);
            calQuery.StartTime = sDate.Date;
            calQuery.EndTime = sDate.AddDays(1); //(EndTime is exclusive calling Google Feeds)
            // Google EventQuery together with StartTime and EndTime returns also Events overlapping! 

            EventFeed myEvents = _calendarService.Query(calQuery);
```

This code should return events only of specified date (sDate). However as per design Google Calendar returns also events overlapping into this date. So if I have an event starting just before midnight the day before and ending the next day it will be returned in this query, as it is overlapping. How can I avoid/prevent overlapping events in such a query? I have not found any hint in Google API nor in other sources.